# encryption or Cryptography for store sensitive data

Tags: php, security, encryption

I have some searches to find out what is the best way to store sensitive data in the database?
for a project, I need to store cryptocurrency wallet's secret key in DB and do this job without consultation is too risky.

I try sodium and maybe use multiple methods for encryption but I don't know what is the best and safest way

```
$secret = 'xxxxx';

$key   = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);
$nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES);

// Encrypt
$ciphertext = sodium_crypto_secretbox($msg, $nonce, $key);
// Decrypt
$plaintext = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($ciphertext, $nonce, $key);
```

if you have experience with cryptography and encryption data please guide me.

## additional information

I use PHP 7.3 and laravel for this project and I want to create a package for anyone of cryptocurrency wallet my this information is good for u can help me better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how encryptions work, actually, there are two types of cryptography

1. Symmetric Cryptography
2. Asymmetric Cryptography (Public Key)

Please check here: http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/securitytools/ddu/ch09lev1sec1.html

Base on your code, you are using Symmetric Cryptography which you used the shared key.
Since you are using laravel, you can store Secret Key in ENV be sure to turn off debugging. Since you are using laravel, you can use the built-in encryption/decryption method found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption

Laravel Built-in encryption uses OpenSSL to provide AES-256 and AES-128 encryption and All of Laravel's encrypted values are signed using a message authentication code (MAC) so that their underlying value can not be modified once encrypted.